# Uploading App to App Store iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, uploading

I am at the step in the app upload process where I am trying to get my app validated. I am at the step that asks for an identity to sign with. When I choose download an identity it says an administrator must request an identity first. I don't know how to import one either. I have payed the hundred dollars and it hasn't expired. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answered

Comment: Have you created a distribution profile at the membercenter?

Comment: How do I check to see if I did?

Comment: I have a distribution certificate in my keychain access if thats what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you done all of these steps?

Go to the Provisioning Portal.

• Under Provisioning click on the "Distribution" tab.

• Make sure that the distribution profile for the app you’re trying to upload exists.If not create one.

• Download the profile, and drag it into the Xcode organizer.

• Then in your app, in the build settings(for the target and the project), under the code signing, make sure all entries match the distribution profile you set up in the provisioning portal.

• Then edit the scheme in Xcode to archive and make sure its set to archive for "iOS Device" and not the simulator.

[image]